# Unbiased performance test for db cloned from SQL Server into mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, benchmarking

I have cloned a database from SQL Server into mySQL and now I need an unbiased performance test to show the difference between them.

The DBs have the same schema and the same data so a straight-forward query should work well.

I want to take a few caveats into consideration:

1. I don't want to retrieve loads of data since that might test how quick the network connections are, rather than the DB speed - the 2 DBs are nowhere near me or each other on the network
2. I don't want the client software to influence the result potentially, so I'll use command line clients SQLCMD and mysql.exe
3. I want to test with techniques that reflect actual production usage, so perhaps massive table scans are not a great idea
4. I want to make sure proprietry caching or other functionality doesn't catch me out, e.g. I've seen SELECT COUNT(*) queries taking initially 10 secs and then only 1 sec thereafter.
5. I want the query to take at least 100 seconds so I can rely on the default SQLCMD down-to-a-second query duration time display, and be sure that networking speed is only a minimal component of the duration.

There is one table (`data`) that has 50 million rows, so I figure I should target that one. Here's 2 tables from the schema that I could use. There's old stuff in there like the permissions stuff which can be ignored.

```
CREATE TABLE forecast (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  globalRead BIT NOT NULL,
  globalWrite BIT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  unitId INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  actualization_date DATETIME NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_forecast PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_forecast_unit FOREIGN KEY (unitId)
    REFERENCES unit(id)
) MAX_ROWS 123456;


CREATE TABLE data (
  forecastId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  valueDate DATE NOT NULL,
  modifiedDate DATE NOT NULL,
  value FLOAT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_data PRIMARY KEY (forecastId, valueDate, modifiedDate),
  CONSTRAINT fk_data_forecastid FOREIGN KEY (forecastId)
    REFERENCES forecast (id)
) MAX_ROWS 123456789;
```

Here's a query and explain from mysql:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(d.value) FROM forecast f INNER JOIN data d ON d.forecastId = f.id;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref         | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | fk_forecast_unit | 5       | NULL        | 44006 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY          | 4       | tardis.f.id |   374 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(d.value) FROM forecast f INNER JOIN data d ON d.forecastId = f.id;
+----------+--------------------+
| COUNT(*) | AVG(d.value)       |
+----------+--------------------+
| 54446441 | -192404867.8813079 |
+----------+--------------------+
1 row in set (14.50 sec)
```

Here is the query plan from SQL Server:

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[globalagg1007],0), [Expr1005]=CASE WHEN [globalagg1009]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [globalagg1011]/CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float(53),[globalagg1009],0) END))
       |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([globalagg1007]=SUM([partialagg1006]), [globalagg1009]=SUM([partialagg1008]), [globalagg1011]=SUM([partialagg1010])))
            |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([partialagg1008]=[partialagg1006]))
                      |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([partialagg1006]=Count(*), [partialagg1010]=SUM([Tardis].[dbo].[data].[value] as [d].[value])))
                           |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Tardis].[dbo].[data].[PK_data] AS [d]))
```

How can I improve on this and does this query fail any of the caveats above?

Is it a fair benchmark?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` is usually a very poor performance indicator... (Cold/hot data et, disk fragmentation etc.)

Comment: Benchmarking is not trivial if you want it to be useful, Like it or not, you will exercise hardware (network, CPU, storage, and memory) rather than just the database platform so the test is measuring how well (or not) the DBMS leverages hardware capabilities. I suggest you read one of the full disclosure reports for the TPC-E or TPC-H benchmarks at http://www.tpc.org/information/benchmarks.asp and construct a test based on your actual expected workload query mix.

Comment: Obviously it would be nice if there was a silver bullet for benchmarking, but I figured I should be able to come up with something in ANSI SQL with maybe 2 or 3 hours effort that gets in the right ball park. If you're saying any of those caveats 1 to 5 are not practical, that's an answer in itself I figure.

Comment: The 2nd thing I can read between the lines of your comment is that just one SQL query is not enough, it should be a mix of selects, updates, and inserts with a timer?